# Sum with variable terms to sum over

Tags: summation, recursion, iteration

Suppose I have a polynomial like this:
$$a=x_{j_1} + x_{j_1}x_{j_2} + x_{j_1}x_{j_2}x_{j_3} + ...+x_{j_1}x_{j_2}x_{j_3}...x_{j_n}$$

I want to create a function that takes this polynomial and does the following:
$$f[a]=\sum_{j_1}^px_{j_1}+\sum_{j_1}^p\sum_{j_2}^{j_1}x_{j_1}x_{j_2}+\sum_{j_1}^p\sum_{j_2}^{j_1}\sum_{j_3}^{j_2}x_{j_1}x_{j_2}x_{j_3}+...+\sum_{j_1}^p\sum_{j_2}^{j_1}\sum_{j_3}^{j_2}...\sum_{j_n}^{j_{n-1}}x_{j_1}x_{j_2}x_{j_3}...x_{j_{n-1}}x_{j_n}$$
where $p$ is a fixed number.

**In practice, my polynomials are not limited to those three variables. The $x$'s are labelled by a unique index $j_i$.** That is what I mean by variable terms to sum over. I am not sure how to make the code 1. recognize that it has $n$ factors in a term (corresponding to $\sum_{j_1>j_2>...>j_n}x_{j_1}x_{j_2}...x_{j_n}$), and 2. sum over those terms.

I looked at a similar question here where it was for $n$ number of terms but I have not been able to successfully adapt that solution.

Comment: Do you have an attempt at a solving this?  Do you have a reference to earlier solutions (and can you include those in a solution attempt)?  Showing functional code that doesn't do what you want would be helpful for anyone looking to provide a solution.

Comment: Do you want $j_1>j_2>\ldots>j_n$ or $j_1\geq j_2\geq \ldots \geq j_n$?  Your definition of `f[a]` doesn't seem to match either one of those restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** A function that takes an expression of the specific form and an integer to construct the desired sums:

```
ClearAll[sumF]
sumF[poly_, p_] :=  Module[{var, indices, iteratorlist, 
   parts = {First@#, #2} & @@ DeleteDuplicates /@ 
      Transpose[Cases[poly /. Subscript[a_, Subscript[b_, c_]] :> 
          Subscript[a, Superscript[b, c]], Subscript[a_, b_] :> {a, b}, All]]},
  {var, indices} = parts;
  iteratorlist = Reverse[Insert[#, 1, 2]&/@ Partition[Reverse@Prepend[indices, p], 2, 1]];
  Total@Table[Sum[Times @@ (Subscript[var, #] & /@ index[[All, 1]]), 
    Evaluate[## & @@ index]], 
   {index, iteratorlist[[;; #]] & /@ Range[Length@indices]}] /. Superscript -> Subscript]
```

**Examples:**

```
poly1 = Subscript[x, i] + Subscript[x, i] Subscript[x, j] + 
   Subscript[x, i] Subscript[x, j] Subscript[x, k];
TeXForm @ poly1
```

> $x_i x_j x_k+x_i x_j+x_i$

```
sumF[poly1, p]
```

[image]

```
poly2 = Subscript[z, i] + Subscript[z, i] Subscript[z, j] + 
  Subscript[z, i] Subscript[z, j] Subscript[z, k] + 
  Subscript[z, i] Subscript[z, j] Subscript[z, k] Subscript[z, m]
TeXForm @ poly2
```

> $z_i z_j z_k z_m+z_i z_j z_k+z_i z_j+z_i$

```
sumF[poly2, p]
```

[image]

```
poly3 = Total[Times@@@(Take[Subscript[w, Subscript[j, #]] & /@ Range[7], #]& /@ Range[7])]
TeXForm[poly3]
```

> $w_{j_2} w_{j_1}+w_{j_2} w_{j_3} w_{j_1}+w_{j_2} w_{j_3} w_{j_4} w_{j_1}+w_{j_2}
>    w_{j_3} w_{j_4} w_{j_5} w_{j_1}+w_{j_2} w_{j_3} w_{j_4} w_{j_5} w_{j_6}
>    w_{j_1}+w_{j_2} w_{j_3} w_{j_4} w_{j_5} w_{j_6} w_{j_7} w_{j_1}+w_{j_1}$

```
sumF[poly3, p]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[sum]
sum[p_, a_: x] := Total@
    Table[Sum[Times @@ (Subscript[a, #] & /@ index[[All, 1]]), Evaluate[## & @@ index]], 
   {index, {{i, 1, p}, {j, 1, i}, {k, 1, j}}[[;; #]] & /@ {1, 2, 3}}]

sum[p]
```

[image]

```
 TeXForm[sum@p]
```

> $\sum _{i=1}^p \sum _{j=1}^i \sum _{k=1}^j x_i x_j x_k+\sum _{i=1}^p \sum _{j=1}^i x_i x_j+\sum
>    _{i=1}^p x_i$

```
sum[3] // TeXForm
```

> $\small x_1^3+x_2 x_1^2+x_3 x_1^2+x_1^2+x_2^2 x_1+x_3^2 x_1+x_2 x_1+x_2 x_3 x_1+x_3
>    x_1+x_1+x_2^3+x_3^3+x_2^2+x_2 x_3^2+x_3^2+x_2+x_2^2 x_3+x_2 x_3+x_3$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the way I posed my question was misleading. Please check the updated version.

Comment: @AlonsoPerezLona, please see the update.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how the right-hand side of `f[a_]` can result from `a` (unless `f` separates each term in `a` rather than keeping the sum intact).

To obtain the right-hand side of `f[a_]` it seems that one only needs to know the maximum number of terms in the products.  Here's a function that will do that:

```
f[n_] := Sum[SymmetricPolynomial[i, Table[Subscript[x, j], {j, n}]], {i, n}]

f[3]
```

$$x_2 x_1+x_2 x_3 x_1+x_3 x_1+x_1+x_2+x_2 x_3+x_3$$

For polynomial functions in the form you're using you should take a look at `AugmentedSymmetricPolynomial`, `PowerSymmetricPolynomial`, `SymmetricReduction`, and `PolynomialReduce`.  Also, *mathStatica* (a *Mathematica* package for purchase) has conversion functions for converting functions such as yours to `PowerSymmetricPolynomial`'s which makes calculations much, much efficient (and makes the calculation even possible when there are zillions of terms).

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
myEquation = \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i\), \(p\)]\(Subscript[x, 
i]\)\) + \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i\), \(p\)]\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j\), \(i\)]Subscript[x, 
  i] Subscript[x, j]\)\) + \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i\), \(p\)]\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j\), \(i\)]\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k\), \(j\)]Subscript[x, i] Subscript[x, j] Subscript[x, k]\)\)\)
```

And then by saying

```
myEquation /. p -> 3
```

You get this:

```
Subscript[x, 1] + 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\), \(2\)]\) + 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\), \(3\)]\) + Subscript[x, 2] + 
 Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2] + \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\), \(2\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\) + 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\), \(2\)]\) + Subscript[x, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\), \(2\)]\) + 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\), \(3\)]\) + Subscript[x, 3] + 
 Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3] + \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\), \(2\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\) + Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 3] + 
 Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 3] + \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\), \(2\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\) + 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\), \(2\)]\) + Subscript[x, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\), \(2\)]\) + Subscript[x, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\), \(2\)]\) + 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\), \(3\)]\)
```

Is this what you were hoping for?

Comment: Of course, it looks nicer in a notebook.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the way I posed my question was misleading. Please check the updated version.

Comment: Got it.  @kglr solution seems quite nice.